# TypeScript Yarn app error while downloading -> SyntaxError: Unexpected token '.'

Tags: javascript, node.js, linux, typescript

So this is my first time using yarn for applications and I'm having this issue:

```
SyntaxError: Unexpected token '.'
    at wrapSafe (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:915:16)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:963:27)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1027:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:863:32)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:708:14)
    at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:887:19)
    at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:74:18)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/home/user/.config/yarn/global/node_modules/@poppinss/utils/build/src/Helpers/index.js:56:31)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:999:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1027:10)
error Command failed.
Exit code: 1
Command: /home/user/.yarn/bin/create-adonis-ts-app
Arguments: cnc
Directory: /home/user
Output:
```

This is the second step of the installation and I'm just running this command: yarn create adonis-ts-app cnc

This first part of the installation looks fine but here it is:

```
yarn create v1.22.18
[1/4] Resolving packages...
[2/4] Fetching packages...
[3/4] Linking dependencies...
[4/4] Building fresh packages...

success Installed "create-adonis-ts-app@4.0.6" with binaries:
      - create-adonis-ts-app
/home/user/.config/yarn/global/node_modules/@poppinss/utils/build/src/Helpers/string.js:241
        return `${values[0]}${options?.pairSeparator || ' and '}${values[1]}`;
```

I'm also new to TS so I don't really know how to handle this errors. Thanks!

(I'm running PopOS)

The command should install the packages and help me with the files but the installation failed in the second step.

Comment: This is a [known issue](https://github.com/poppinss/utils/issues/21) with AdonisJS when using node version lower than v14.15.4. This requirement is also documented in  [the installation guide](https://docs.adonisjs.com/guides/installation). Check your node version with `node --version` at the command line.

Answer (score 0):

I had this error a while ago when I upgraded to **NodeJS v16.14.0**.
Going back to **v16.13.2** fixed it for me.
It seems to be a bug in NodeJS.

Answer (score -1):

it's just a syntax error.
Please review your code once.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).